# Not able to return arraylist outside the scope, it becomes null

Tags: java, android, arraylist, return

When i am copying the data obtained(contained in arraylist) into a new arraylist and returning it, the new arraylist does not return any value.
onDataReceived(ArrayList arrayList) is the listener callback method after the data has been asynchronously fetched through volley in arraylist.

```
package com.example.bike.ViewModels;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.example.bike.Models.BikesInfo;
import com.example.bike.Repository.BikesRepository;
import com.example.bike.Repository.Listener;
import com.example.bike.Views.ApplicationContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BikesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
 private BikesRepository bikesRepository;
 public static ArrayList<BikesInfo> vmarrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 public BikesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
     bikesRepository = new BikesRepository(application, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(ArrayList<BikesInfo> arrayList) {

                vmarrayList.addAll(arrayList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }
        });
        bikesRepository.getArrayList();

    }

public ArrayList<BikesInfo> getbikesinfolistobservable(){
       return vmarrayList;
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.bike.Views.ui;

import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.bike.Models.BikesInfo;
import com.example.bike.R;
import com.example.bike.ViewModels.BikesViewModel;
import com.example.bike.Views.Adapters.BikesListAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BikesViewModel bikesViewModel;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    BikesListAdapter bikesListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bikes_recycler);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        bikesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(BikesViewModel.class);

        bikesListAdapter = new BikesListAdapter(bikesViewModel.getbikesinfolistobservable());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(bikesListAdapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Mostly because the method 'getbikesinfolistobeservable' is called before the callback 'OnDataReceived'. Check the execution in debug mode.

Comment: is vmarrayList empty or null? if its null check if its being changed from outside this class. If its empty is probably because of the execution order.

Comment: Also, why is the variable static if you are going to use a getter?

Comment: @Marco I think you are right, i am getting data late. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: @EugenioValeiras vmarraylist is empty at first but i am copying another arraylist in it and then returning it

Comment: @Osama I need to see the code to help you, share the portion of code where you call 'getbikesinfolistobservable'.
Easily you can use a something like a Barrier (CountDownLatch) and call the method from a secondary thread. Or maybe you need to re-work on your logic to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: You're not properly using the `ViewModel` and `Repository` in this case. I would suggest rewrite it using the `MutableLiveData` and by removing `Listener` interface.

Comment: @Marco I have updated above the class where the 'getbikesinfolistobservable' method has been called.

Comment: @Osama you need to wait for data being retrieved from the backend, so you can show a ProgressBar while you do that and initialise the adapter inside the callback or be able to call 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' inside the callback (you need a reference to the adapter to do that)

Comment: @SrikarReddy Will MutableLiveData serve the purpose of Listener if i remove it? Can you point out where the mistake could be?

Comment: Thank you, @Marco ,@SrikarReddy ,LiveData worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using volley to make a request you cannot ensure the call of getbikesinfolistobservable() will be executed after the request finshed, as its an async request.

Try to do a console log on vmarrayList after vmarrayList.addAll(arrayList). If it's still empty then ArrayList arrayList is empty too, so it would be a problem with the request's response.

Also vmarrayList is a static variable and class BikesViewModel is public, so you won't need a getter.

Comment: I have checked that the 'arraylist' in 'onDataReceived(ArrayList<BikesInfo> arrayList)' is not empty. It has the fetched json data.

Comment: did you try this _"Try to do a console log on vmarrayList after vmarrayList.addAll(arrayList)"_ then?

Comment: yes, but not exactly console log instead i used break point to see whether the arraylist was empty or not and it was not.

Comment: Are you sure you are waiting for the request to finish before calling getbikesinfolistobservable() ?

Comment: NO, i am not sure, i think this is the problem as also told by Marco above in comments. I don't know exactly how to solve it.

Comment: As Marco said:  You can set an observable on the variable and subscribe as an observer where you are calling getbikesinfolistobservable(). 

checkout this out : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel